# Mutually clickable overlayed elements

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, overlay, blocking

Okay, so I'm finding a lot of answers that don't quite fit my need.  Here is my scenario:  I have an app in javascript/html/css.  I have two independently rotatable overlayed elements (in this case both svg's) that both have elements that need to be clickable which move around their perimers with the rotation of the two elements.  One layer has 7 clickable points, the other has 12 clickable points, and the two rotate to a given point based on onclick events that set a target degree for the rotation.  Only the points (i.e. small transparent circles at the edge of a circular radius on each of the two svg's) need to be clickable.  My problem is that whichever layer I put on top works, but the buttons on the other layer then stop working, apparently blocked by the other's background.  I've tried messing with all sorts of pointer events and some other ideas on StackOverflow, but all end with the same result:  one set of buttons doesn't work.  They need to be on separate layers so the rotation will put them at the correct position as they rotate in real-time.  Any ideas would be welcome.  I am looking for an answer that requires no libraries (including jquery), however if it can be done with jquery, then it can be done without jquery-- if I can find out how.  Ideas anyone?

Comment: you might try playing with `pointer-events:none;`, applying it to the container, and over-riding it (`pointer-events:all;`) on the clickable parts, but i'm not sure that will work.

Comment: close.  found the answer long time ago, but happened upon my own question looking for something else.  the answer is style 'pointer-events: none;' on the parent element, and 'pointer-events: auto;' on child elements you want clickable.  this will make only the elements set to 'auto' consume clicks, touches, etc. and allow them to pass through the parent element to anything under/behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dandavis is pretty much right here, except I think he meant to say pointer-events: auto .  Was just noting there's not an official 'answer' posted.  For now, marking this one, but if you want to re-post as an 'answer', Dan, I will gladly mark it as the accepted one.